# How could I extend my user model with field profile_image = models.FileField()?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-users

I have created a form and have all criterias of name, email, password but not the image. In order to create "upload image" option, I am in need to extend my user model with field

```
profile_image = models.FileField()
```

Do help.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  image = models.ImageField()
```

This way i follow to extend user model. But for better solution you can follow this link https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html